# Abaqus Python script to open several odb files by variable name

Tags: python

I have a txt-file called "odbList.txt" which contains the names of several odb-files.

```
plate_2mm.odb
plate_4mm.odb
plate_6mm.odb
```

Now I wrote a Python Script, where I want to open each of these files in a loop.

```
    # list of ODB-Files
    odbList = [ ]
    f = file( 'W:/someDirectory/odbList.txt' , 'r')
    count = 0
    for line in f.readlines() :
        odbList.append (line)
        count = count + 1

    def getSIF(case, i):
        odb = openOdb(path = 'W:/someDirectory/' + case)

    # start analyses for each case
    for i in xrange(0,count):
        getSIF(odbList[i], i)
```

I get the following error message:

```
OdbError: Cannot open file W:/someDirectory/plate_2mm.odb
. *** ERROR: No such file: W:/someDirectory/plate_2mm.odb
```

The weird thing however is that it works perfectly fine when I hardcode the complete path.

Another weird thing. If I use this line instead:

```
odb = openOdb(path = case)
```

I get following error message:

```
OdbError: Cannot open file C:/Temp/plate_2mm.odb
. *** ERROR: No such file: C:/Temp/plate_2mm.odb
```

And if I transfer all my files into C:/Temp everything works fine. But why doesn't it work if I use the first version / a different folder? Especially since it is working when hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times when I open a file I use the following:

`f=open(file_name,'r')
    s=f.read().splitlines()
    f.close()
    while '' in s:
        s.remove('')`

You will now have a list in s without enters.

Alternatively you can use something like

`import os
odbList=[]
for fileN in os.listdir("."):
    if '.odb' in fileN:
        odbList.append(fileN)`

This will find all files containing .odb in the name in the script's directory/working directory

Comment: The first piece of code solved my problem. Also using line.rstrip() in my original code worked (like Aaron suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried entering your string as a raw string like this`odb = openOdb(path = r'W:/someDirectory/' + case)` or usining the os.sep character like this: `odb = openOdb(path = 'W:someDirectory' + os.sep + case)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that did not work. But I noticed something else. If odbList.txt contains only one line (only one file name) it works. Maybe the linebreak is not read correctly???

Comment: You could try adding a lstrip and rstrip to the case object to remove any whitespace characters and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Inserting "line = line.rstrip()" as the first line in the for-Loop worked. Thank you!